# How to install spacy and avoid 32/64 bit error?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I tried to execute

`pip install spacy`

and it finally worked with Python 3.7 64 bit (not with 32 bit version) but after installation no other package imports like pandas are working. It seems that the installation is the root cause but after removing spacy the import error of pandas and many other packages is still the same.

After reinstalling python (I always install it directly in folder C:\Python), 
I can sucessfully install pandas and all the other packages without the error below but I still cannot use Spacy as I would get the import error:

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32-Application

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd

c:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
      9 for dependency in hard_dependencies:
     10     try:
---> 11         __import__(dependency)
     12     except ImportError as e:
     13         missing_dependencies.append("{0}: {1}".format(dependency, str(e)))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    138 
    139     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
    142     from . import core

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
     24                 # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
     25                 # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
---> 26                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     27                 DLL_filenames.append(filename)
     28     if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

c:\python\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    362 
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:
    366             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 ist keine zulässige Win32-Anwendung´´´
```

Comment: Do you think you could translate the error message?

Comment: Yeah sure: "%1 is not a valid win32-Application".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have two different `site-package` folders from where packages are imported:

```
c:\python\lib\site-packages
```

and

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
```

Which looks to me like there is currently a mix of different python installations on your systems or residues of previously installed and then incompletely removed versions. I would therefore suggest to:

1. Remove all python installations
2. Completely remove both `c:\python` and `~\AppData\Roaming\Python`
3. Reinstall only one python distribution. Choose the 64bit version if you don't care which version to use

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer solved my problem. Additionally I have now a clean new and single python environment.